# XML Processing not working

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am trying to extract data from a sensor (it communicate with "xml type" strings) and convert it to csv.
With my actual code i already write xml files, but the data come in single rows (from root to /root it is).

Dunno if this is the reason but i get a **elementtree.parse error junk after document element**. Everything that i've read so far, the problem was in xml construction (more than one root, no root, etc) so i'm a bit at loss with my case.

Logged in xml file:

```
<li820><data><celltemp>5.1120729e1</celltemp><cellpres>9.7705745e1</cellpres><co2>7.7808494e2</co2><co2abs>5.0983281e-2</co2abs><ivolt>1.1380004e1</ivolt><raw>2726238,1977386</raw></data></li820>
<li820><data><celltemp>5.1120729e1</celltemp><cellpres>9.7684698e1</cellpres><co2>7.7823929e2</co2><co2abs>5.0991268e-2</co2abs><ivolt>1.1380004e1</ivolt><raw>2725850,1976922</raw></data></li820>
<li820><data><celltemp>5.1120729e1</celltemp><cellpres>9.7705745e1</cellpres><co2>7.7797288e2</co2><co2abs>5.0977463e-2</co2abs><ivolt>1.1373291e1</ivolt><raw>2726166,1977001</raw></data></li820>
```

Content of one of the previous row (in tree view) :

```
<li820>
    <data>
        <celltemp>1.9523970e1</celltemp>
        <cellpres>9.8993663e1</cellpres>
        <co2>3.5942180e4</co2>
        <co2abs>4.0364418e-1</co2abs>
        <ivolt>1.1802978e1</ivolt>
        <raw>2789123,1884335</raw>
    </data>
</li820>
```

Error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "licor_read.py", line 96, in <module>
  tree = et.parse(file_xml)              # Set XML Parser
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
  tree.parse(source, parser)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
  parser.feed(data)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
  self._raiseerror(v)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
  raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 2, column 0
```

My code :

```
import os, sys, subprocess
import time, datetime
import serial
import string
import glob
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree  as et

from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser, XML, fromstring, tostring
from os  import path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


#-------------------------------------------------------------
#------------------ Open configurations ----------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------------

  ############
  # Settings #
  ############

DEBUG   = True
LOG     = True
FREQ    = 1
PORT    = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
BAUD    = 9600
PARITY  = 'N'
STOPBIT = 1
BYTE_SZ = 8
TIMEOUT = 5.0

log_dir   = 'logs/'
out_dir   = 'export/'
fname_xml = 'licor820-data-{}.xml'.format(datetime.datetime.now())            # DO NOT touch the {} brackets
fname_csv = 'licor820-data-{}.csv'.format(datetime.datetime.now())            #
isLooping = 20                                                                # Nr of data extractions
isHeader  = True                                                              # Do not touch if data headers are required
isBegin   = False


#-------------------------------------------------------------
#----- Better know what you are doing from this point --------
#-------------------------------------------------------------

  ##################
  # Initialisation #
  ##################

file_xml = os.path.join(log_dir, fname_xml)                                   # Define path and file name
file_csv = os.path.join(out_dir, fname_csv)                                   #
fp_xml   = open(file_xml, 'w')                                                # Open writing streams
fp_csv   = open(file_csv, 'w')                                                #

try:
  buff = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD, BYTE_SZ, PARITY, STOPBIT, TIMEOUT)         # Open Serial connection
except Exception as e:
  if DEBUG:
    print ("ERROR: {}".format(e))

  sys.exit("Could not connect to the Licor")

csv_writer    = csv.writer(fp_csv)                                            # Define CSV writer
instruct_head = []                                                            # '' 


  ################
  # Main program #
  ################

while isLooping :                                                             # Define nr of refreshed data extracted
  #os.system('clear')
  print('RAW/XML in progress... ' + str(isLooping))                           # Debug this loop

  if(isBegin is False) :                                                      # Verify presence of the <licor> tag
    while(buff.readline()[0] is not '<' and buff.readline()[1] is not 'l') :    
      raw_output = buff.readline()                                            # Jump the lines readed until <licor>
  isBegin = True

  raw_output = buff.readline()
  xml_output = raw_output

  print(xml_output)
  fp_xml.write(xml_output)                                                    # Write from serial port to xml 

  isLooping -= 1

fp_xml.close()

tree = et.parse(file_xml)                                                     # Set XML Parser
root = tree.getroot()                                                         # ''

for instruct_row in root.findall('li820'):                                    # XML to CSV buffer
  instruct = []

  if isHeader is True:                                                        # Buffering header
    celltemp = instruct_row.find('celltemp').tag
    instruct_head.append(celltemp)
    cellpres = instruct_row.find('cellpres').tag
    instruct_head.append(cellpres)      
    co2 = instruct_row.find('co2').tag
    instruct_head.append(co2)      
    co2abs = instruct_row.find('co2abs').tag
    instruct_head.append(co2abs)      
    ivolt = instruct_row.find('ivolt').tag
    instruct_head.append(ivolt)      
    raw = instruct_row.find('raw').tag
    instruct_head.append(raw)

    csv_writer.writerow(instruct_head)                                        # Write header      
    isHeader = False

  celltemp = instruct_row.find('celltemp').text                               # Buffering data
  instruct.append(celltemp)    
  cellpres = instruct_row.find('cellpres').text
  instruct.append(cellpres)    
  co2 = instruct_row.find('co2').text
  instruct.append(co2)    
  co2abs = instruct_row.find('co2abs').text
  instruct.append(co2abs)      
  ivolt = instruct_row.find('ivolt').text
  instruct.append(ivolt)      
  raw = instruct_row.find('raw').text
  instruct.append(raw)

  csv_writer.writerow(instruct)                                             # Write data'''

csv_writer.close()
fp_csv.close()
os.system('clear')

print('Job done. \nSaved at : ./' + file_xml + '\nAnd at ./' + file_csv + '\n')
```

Comment: Is that first snippet your XML input? It is not well-formed XML as it lacks a root element containing all other elements so I think that is what causes the error message.

Comment: the root is <li820>
every row is a complete tree

Comment: As @MartinHonnen mentions, your XML needs to wrap **all** rows in a root element to be well-formed, not just individuals rows: `<root>...content...</root>`. So each `<li820>` is a child to root.

Comment: indeed that worked after have changed my xml structure, thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open your input file by 'read' instead of 'write'. Or you will empty your file when you run your code.

```
fp_xml   = open(file_xml, 'r');
```

Besides, I have a better way to get all elements.You don't need to know what the names of all tags ahead of time.

```
header = []
isHeader = True
for instruct_row in root.getchildren():  # XML to CSV buffer
    instruct = []

    for i,item in enumerate(instruct_row.getchildren()):
        if isHeader is True:
            header.append(item.tag)
        instruct.append(item.text)
    isHeader = False
    csv_writer.writerow(instruct)# Write data'''
fp_csv.close()
```

My input xml is below:

```
<li820>
<data><celltemp>5.1120729e1</celltemp><cellpres>9.7705745e1</cellpres><co2>7.7808494e2</co2><co2abs>5.0983281e-2</co2abs><ivolt>1.1380004e1</ivolt><raw>2726238,1977386</raw></data>
<data><celltemp>5.1120729e1</celltemp><cellpres>9.7705745e1</cellpres><co2>7.7808494e2</co2><co2abs>5.0983281e-2</co2abs><ivolt>1.1380004e1</ivolt><raw>2726238,1977386</raw></data>
</li820>
```

Finally you can see data in you csv file.

Comment: wonderful, tried this morning at work, it did the job like a charm.

Comment: @LaurentFournier  It is my pleasure to help and adopt my answer.